# find exact gene list of genes and return 1

Tags: excel

So I have a reference list of genes in excel in one column. In other list I have results of genes from my analysis. I want to make formula that would search whole reference list of genes for each gene from my analysis and write number 1 if there is a match. I tried with IFERROR, SEARCH and VLOOKUP functions and no success so far. Please help. Thank you in advance.

So for examle: in my analysis I found gene ACSL3. What I want to do is to check if that gene is in reference list and if it is I want to have number 1 written or something that tells me that gene from my analysis is in reference list.

I tried this: IFERROR(SEARCH(G29;'Localization reference'!$A$31:$A$54);1)
so the G29 is gene from my analysis (ACSL3), localisation reference is reference list of genes. This formula isn't working properly.

Comment: What do you mean by abbreviations? How can you tell if the search term has a match in the reference list? Some sample data would be helpful.

Comment: You could try `=(MATCH(G29;'Localization reference'!$A$31:$A$54; 0)` - gives you the relative row or #N/A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "reference list" is `A1:A100` and you want to know if the contents of cell `B1` is in that list, you can use

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,$A$1:$A$100,1,false)
```

to return the matching value in column `A`. Using `1` as the third argument is a special case of using `VLOOKUP` where it just returns the same value you searched for (return the value in the first column when you're only using one column).

This is good enough for a quick search, but if you must return `0` or `1`, you can wrap this formula in `ISNA`:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1,$A$1:$A$100,1,false)),0,1)
```

to return `0` if the `VLOOKUP` returns `#N/A` (if a value isn't found by a `VLOOKUP` this is what it returns) or `1` if the value is present.

Answer (score 0):

If your gene is in **A1** and the full list is in column **C**, then in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,C:C,0)),"",1)
```

[image]

*(the formula should also work for genetic abbreviations.)*